# Split string with no delimiter in half (leading letters and trailing number)

Tags: php, string, split

How can I separate the leading letter from the trailing number in each of the sample strings AND remove the unneeded zero-padding from the number?

```
$ab = "A00000001"
echo $a; // gives result "A"
echo $b; // gives result "1"

$ab = "B01250"
echo $a; // gives result "B"
echo $b; // gives result "1250"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ab = "A0000000001";
$a = substr( $ab, 0, 1 );
$b = (int)substr( $ab, 1 );
```

More information about substr can be found here: http://us.php.net/substr

Comment: Updated to assume that the second "part" is always an integer

Comment: This also assumes there the alphabetic portion is never more than one character (of course, that is the indication of the sample input in the question, but it may not be for all applications).

Answer (score 2):

This is shorter, if that's what you mean by "easiet single way":

```
list($a,$b) = preg_split('/0+/',$ab);
```

Adjust your regex if you like:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: What if 0 isn't the first number after the offset?

Comment: This answer corrupts the output and must not be used.  See that `0` after `125`? It is destroyed by the unlimited explosions of `preg_split()`.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/TGi2e

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a regex:

```
  preg_match('@^(\w)0*(\d+)@', $input, $match);
  $letter = $match[1];
  $number = $match[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible, direct, and type-considered approach will be to use `sscanf()`. The function (and its "format" expression) will allow the matching of 1 or more uppercase letters followed by a potentially zero-padded integer.

The output will be a 2-element array containing the leading alphabetical string and then an int-type number.  This is great for professional devs that prefer to maintain clean, rigid data types in their applications.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eNPbF))

```
$tests = ['A00000001', 'B01250'];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    var_export(sscanf($test, '%[A-Z]%d'));
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => 1,
)
array (
  0 => 'B',
  1 => 1250,
)
```

---

`sscanf()` also permits declaring/populating the variables via parameters. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LPDdP))

```
sscanf($test, '%[A-Z]%d', $a, $b);
var_export(['a' => $a, 'b' => $b]);
```

To retain leading zeros or handle integers greater than PHP allows, replace `%d` with `%[0-9]`. This will return the numeric segment as a string.